# How to get a css property of an externally styled element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

lets say i have a div style externally like this

```
 .box{
  background: red;
 }
```

then maybe in javascript i want to toggle the background color, so i have to check first if it has a partcular background color before applying

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

if(box.style.background=='red'){

box.style.background='pink';
}else{
box.style.background='red';

}
```

NOTE: i am not using this for development just a js student

To add a tiny question, if i want to apply css transition to the background change how will that be applied.

the below code works though but i feel there is a cleaner way

```
if(!box.style.background){ //this is because background property is null when reading from external css

    box.style.background='pink';

}else{

    box.style.background="";
}
```

but for the transition i tried applying the transition

```
 box.style.WebkitTransition='background 0.5s easeout';
```

but didnt transits

Comment: Ask **one** question per question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, i will do just that now

Comment: You can use the "edit" link to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the *computed* style of an element (e.g., with stylesheets applied), you use `getComputedStyle`:

```
var box = /*...get a specific element...*/;
var style = getComputedStyle(box);
// Use the properties on `style`, which are like the ones on `element.style`
```

On older IE, you use the `currentStyle` property of the element instead. You can partially polyfill `getComputedStyle` like this:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyle = function(element, pseudoElement) {
        if (pseudoElement) {
            throw "The second argument for getComputedStyle cannot be polyfilled";
        }
        return element.currentStyle;
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
  window.getComputedStyle = function(element, pseudoElement) {
    if (pseudoElement) {
      throw "The second argument for getComputedStyle cannot be polyfilled";
    }
    return element.currentStyle;
  };
}


var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var style = getComputedStyle(foo);
if (style) {
  snippet.log("Current color of #foo is: " + style.color);
}
```

```css
.box {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="box">This is a box</div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```